# Can I mount a 2.4" monitor onto Raspberry Pi Zero through GPIO pins?

Tags: gpio, power, display, pi-zero

Can I mount the 2.4" monitor onto the Pi Zero, through the 40 GPIO pins, after they are soldered on them?

I am referring to this monitor: [Adafruit 2.4" PiTFT HAT with Resistive Touchscreen Mini Kit](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-2-4-pitft-hat-with-resistive-touchscreen-mini-kit).

It says it's designed for:

> It's designed to fit nicely onto the Pi Model A+, B+ or Pi 2.

However would it work on the Raspberry Pi Zero as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why not.  There's another page [about those screens here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pitft-28-inch-resistive-touchscreen-display-raspberry-pi/faq?view=all) that states the backlight uses 75 mA @ 5V (it also says a boost converter is used, but that may only be for the next size up), and the 5V rail should be good for at least 1 A presuming the supply is sufficient.

That page also explicitly refers to the Pi Zero in the download link for OS images.  Some of the Adafruit TFTs have support in the normal kernel, but apparently the smaller ones require something special, which is a bit of a downside, but at least the current custom image is fairly current.  In case the point isn't clear, beware this means you need to use an Adafruit image, and not stock Raspbian.

The same links can be found [via the product page here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-2-4-pitft-hat-with-resistive-touchscreen-mini-kit/easy-install), and again the Zero is explicitly mentioned.

> through the 40 GPIO pins, after they are soldered on them?

The header on the Zero is identical to the other 40 pin models (except without the pins).

Comment: Thanks, I am wondering whether I can use the Raspbian image, with it? For example I don't care about the touchscreen function that much, would it work without touchscreen, with the normal Raspbian?

Comment: I don't know.  Adafruit seem very community oriented though and have various lines of inquiry -- if you ask them I am sure they will be happy to be honest with you.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer (goldilocks) is correct. I just wanted to add the steps without having to navigate to another [site](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-2-4-pitft-hat-with-resistive-touchscreen-mini-kit/easy-install).

In the Pi terminal:

1. `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/adafruit/Raspberry-Pi-Installer-Scripts/master/adafruit-pitft.sh`
2. `chmod +x adafruit-pitft.sh`
3. `sudo ./adafruit-pitft.sh`
4. Choose your correct screen size
5. Choose rotation (this can be changed later if wrong by running `./adafruit-pitft.sh` again
6. "Would you like the console to appear on the PiTFT display"
     "Y" = No GUI (terminal only) "N" = goes to next GUI question asking about HDMI in which you choose "Y" to have the desktop environment on PiTFT and through HDMI.

This was done with Pi Zero W ZH, 2.8" Adafruit TFT/touch, Raspbian stretch w/ Desktop, Kernel 4.14, April 2019 release.